# Run command automatically on login

Tags: command-line, bash, login

I have a command to run a python program. I do not want to run this command manually after login, I want this command should run automatically after I logged in to my ubuntu. I am using Ubuntu 16.04.

Here is the command.

```
sh demo_darknet_yolov3.sh
```

This shell script is placed in this directory 
/MobileNet-YOLO-master/MobileNet-YOLO-master

Comment: Search for `Startup Applications` app in the activity panel.

Answer (score 0):

The commented duplicate has more answers, many of them outdated. Some suggests to type `Startup application` in the dash which is works, but you have to type it in your language - more exactly the default language of installation. This may hard to guess.

My advice is to press the super key (for open the dash) and start typing gnome-session-properties (or just run it from terminal).

Comment: There is [an answer already covering that](https://askubuntu.com/a/514132/250300). You should [upvote](https://askubuntu.com/help/privileges/vote-up) it if you find it useful.

Comment: You are right, but there are more factors because i had to do this instead. 1) Cant upvote (yet), 2. Not found any answer which is containing the hotkey for dash. 3) Not found any answer which is containing both dash and gnome-session-properties. 4) The missleading answer has soo high reputation. 5) The linked question is such a mess for now anyway :) 6) I hope someone googling for „run command automatically” with ubuntu version, like 16.04, 18.04 or 19.04 will find this question instead of that.

Comment: With 19 reputation points, you _can_ upvote already!

Comment: Thx. Just did. Only five more reasons to go :)